# reactjs pre-select radio button

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, checked

I have a section in Client`s panel to agree (or not) to receive promo emails.
I set this as a choice of two radio buttons, yes or no.

Technically everything is working just fine, I can store proper information in the DB but the initial state of radio buttons is not showing. The proper value is being sent ot its 'parent' but it seems it's not passed down to the actual form.

What I would like to achieve is the initial radio button being checked (true, false):

[image]
[image]

The info is being sent (in line 52, **[PROMO_CONSENT]: promo_consent**):

```
        [PROMO_CONSENT_FORM]: {
        label: _t(panelMessages.promos),
        data: Promo,
        form: {
            formId: PROMO_CONSENT_FORM,
            data: {
                [PROMO_CONSENT]: promo_consent
            }
        }
    }
```

but then it doesn't seems to show anywhere else. To manage the states of radiobuttons, component FormChoiceGroup is being called **component: FormChoiceGroup,**.

```
        [PROMO_CONSENT_FORM]: {
        formId: [PROMO_CONSENT_FORM],
        endpoint: '/accounts/set_promo/',
        fields: [
            {
                name: PROMO_CONSENT,
                label: _t(panelMessages.promoLabel),
                component: FormChoiceGroup,
                type: 'radio',
                isRequired: false
            }
        ]
    }
```

It's a lot of code, if anyone feels like going through it, I'd appreciate it.

Block:
[Panel main block](https://codepen.io/gregbialowas/pen/jxpXKK?editors=0010)

Form:
[Panel form, the part of consent starts at line 96](https://codepen.io/gregbialowas/pen/bMjOQL?editors=0010)

ChoiceGroup:
[Component to manage radio buttons](https://codepen.io/gregbialowas/pen/ZojVVP?editors=0010)

Comment: Can you post ChoiceInput also?

Comment: Here it is: https://codepen.io/gregbialowas/pen/OZwqKN?editors=0010

Comment: I see in the `ChoiceInput` component you have the `checked` prop setting it to `true` for no input would work fine

Comment: I found the problem: I had to send NOT a boolean value, but turn it into a string. When the string was received, the radio buttons started to work. Now I've been facing another problem - when the initial state is selected the "handleChange" even kinda stopped working :)   Thank you very much for your time! Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to send NOT a boolean value, but turn it into a string, to send literal "true" or "false" and not true/false.

I set up a **const** that checked the status of the variable and then assigned it with literal values:

```
const val = this.state.formData[field.name] == false ? "false" : "true";
```

This simple thing did the trick.